# How to edit android layout code template

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, xml-layout

When I edit layout.xml I input "<"Text and press Ctrl+Space, see TextView in a list and press Enter to add TextView-element on the file. IDE insert the following:

```
<TextView android:layout_width="" android:layout_height=""/>
```

How to edit this code template that IDE insert code in the following format:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width=""
    android:layout_height=""
    />
```

Comment: Hi @ilyamuromets please refer to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) link to get more understanding about layout and how to use them.

Comment: Please read more about programming for the android platform before you ask questions. Knowledge is the key

Comment: You didn't understand me. Perhaps because of my poor English. I want to change the template on which IDE inserts autocompletion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question:

In Android Studio File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> XML. Then click on Android Tab, find title "Layout Files", set "Wrap Attributes" to "Wrap always" and check three items.